# Verifying $|F(r)| \geq \frac{1}{1-r}\log(\frac{1}{1-r}) $ and $|F(re^{i \theta})| \geq c_{q/r}\frac{1}{1-r}\log({\log(\frac{1}{1-r})})$

Tags: complex-analysis, tauberian-theory

I'm attempting to take a Tauberian route in verifying the proposition in $(1)$ below, which is from *Complex Analysis*, by Elias M Stein and Rami M. Shakarchi.

Let $F(z)$ be the following series:

$$F(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}d(n)z^{n} \, \, \text{for} \, |z| < 1$$

$\text{Remark}$

One can also observe the following relationship:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}d(n)z^{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{1-z^{n}}$$

$(1)$

If $z=r$ with $0 < r < 1$, then as $r \rightarrow 1$, another case that be considered is $\theta=\frac{2\pi p}{q}$, where $p$ and $q$ are positive integers and then:

$(1.2)$

$$|F(r)| \geq \frac{1}{1-r}\log\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right)$$

$(1.3)$
$$\lvert F(re^{i \theta})\rvert \geq c_{q/r}\frac{1}{1-r}\log\left(\frac{1}{1-r}\right)$$

$\text{Lemma}$

Formally attacking $(1)$, one can make the initial observations for the case seen in $(1.2)$

$$\left\lvert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{1-z^{n}}\right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{1-r}\log\left( \frac{1}{1-r}\right)$$
$$\left\lvert\frac{z^{1}}{1-z^{1}} + \frac{z^{2}}{1-z^{2}} + \frac{z^{3}}{1-z^{3}} + \frac{z^{4}}{1-z^{4}} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{z^{n}}{1-z^{n}}\right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{1-r}\log\left( \frac{1}{1-r}\right)$$

Recall the archetypal technique of Abel summability as formally developed in $(2)$:

$(2)$

$\text{Definition  (0.2)}$

A series $A(r)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}r^{n}$ is said to Abel summable to $L$ if  $f(r)$ is convergent for all $\lvert r\rvert < L$ and if $f(r)$ converges to some limit $L$ as $r \rightarrow 1^{-}$:
$$A(r)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}r^{n}$$

$\text{Remark}$:

The developments of Abel summability, expressed within a prior definition, can be fully expressed as follows:

$$\lim_{r \rightarrow 1^{}} A(r)= \lim_{r \rightarrow 1^{}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}r^{n} = L$$

Now recall our previous observation with some added developments:
$$\left|\frac{z^{1}}{1-z^{1}} + \frac{z^{2}}{1-z^{2}} + \frac{z^{3}}{1-z^{3}} + \frac{z^{4}}{1-z^{4}} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{z^{n}}{1-z^{n}} = d(1)z^{1}  + d(2)z^{2} + d(3)z^{3} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + d(4)z^{4} + d(z)z^{n}\right| \leq \frac{1}{1-r}\log\left( \frac{1}{1-r}\right)$$

$$\left|d(1)z^{1}  + d(2)z^{2} + d(3)z^{3} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + d(4)z^{4} + d(z)z^{n}\right| \leq \frac{1}{1-r}\log\left( \frac{1}{1-r}\right)$$

$$\lim_{r \rightarrow 1^{}}|d(1)z^{1}  + d(2)z^{2} + d(3)z^{3} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + d(4)z^{4} + d(z)z^{n}| \leq \frac{1}{1-r}\log\left( \frac{1}{1-r}\right)$$

Are the recent developments valid so far? I feel like this approach is too "archetypal." If the developments are wrong, may I have an answer on an alternate approach?

Comment: Looking back at the question it could be possible for one to use tools from "Residue Theory" for the case:$|F(re^{i \theta})| \geq c_{q/r}\frac{1}{1-r}\log(\frac{1}{1-r})$, as follows:      $$|F(re^{i \theta})| \geq c_{q/r}\frac{1}{1-r}\log(\frac{1}{1-r})$$
$$|F(re^{i \frac{2 \pi p}{q}})| \geq c_{q/r}\frac{1}{1-r}\log(\frac{1}{1-r})$$

$$|\sum_{}^{}d(n)^{\frac{2 \pi p}{q} }| \geq c_{q/r}\frac{1}{1-r}\log(\frac{1}{1-r})$$


$$f(z) = d(n)^{\frac{2 \pi p}{q} }$$

$$\text{Res}[ \pi cot \pi z \, d(n)^{\frac{2 \pi p}{q} }]$$ Then apply the Residue Theorem, but i'm not proficient enough in CA

Comment: to attempt this approach.

Comment: One approach is to use the fact that if $f$ is a positive, monotonically decreasing function, then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) \geq \int_1^\infty f(t)\,dt.$$

Comment: Also I don't know what it would mean for a development to be "too archetypal".

Comment: Well in the context of Stein's book series: Lectures on Analysis. In the first book he introduces some Sumability Methods, Abel, Ceasro,etc and adapts them for various problems and developments. The sumability techniques he introduces appears constantly throughout the series, and can be used to deal with a lot of the exercises.

Comment: Also I need some more clarifications, on the fact you just gave, where does the fact: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n) \geq \int_1^\infty f(t)\,dt. $ come from ?

Comment: It comes from $$\int_1^\infty f(t)\,dt = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_n^{n+1} f(t)\,dt \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_n^{n+1} f(n)\,dt = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n).$$

Comment: So that's the upper and lower bounds for the infinite series

Comment: Also was my approach exploiting Abel-Summability initially valid and correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case of (1.2), note that

$$1-r^n = (1-r)(1+r+r^2+\cdots + r^{n-1}) \le (1-r)\cdot n.$$

Therefore

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^n}{1-r^n}\ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^n}{(1-r)n} = \frac{1}{1-r}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^n}{n}.$$

But the sum on the right is precisely $\ln\left (\dfrac{1}{1-r}\right ).$ This gives your (1.2).

Comment: Thanks I was really stuck on this also can you clearify the steps made in the following observation:$1-r^n = (1-r)(1+r+r^2+\cdots + r^{n-1}) \le (1-r)\cdot n.$, i'm sorry for not being able to answer it and only making partial progress :(.

Comment: @Zophikel Each term of the sum $1+r+r^2 +\cdots +r^{n-1}$ is $\le 1.$ There are $n$ terms. Therefore the sum has to be $\le n\cdot 1 = n.$

Comment: all right also where did the sum:$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^n}{(1-r)n}$ come from ?.

Comment: @Zophikel  $1-r^n\le (1-r)n $ implies $r^n/(1-r^n) \ge r^n/[(1-r)n].$

Comment: i'm still not understanding where did you get: $r^n(1-r^n) \ge r^n/[(1-r)n].$ from ?

Comment: @Zophikel   We have two fractions: $\dfrac{r^n}{1-r^n}$ and $ \dfrac{r^n}{(1-r)n}.$ The second one has the same numerator as the first one, but a larger denominator. Therefore the second fraction is smaller.

Comment: ahhhh ok now I understand, can you give me a hint on an alternative way to prove this. also was my first attempt accurate or on the right track ?