# $|F(re^{i\theta})|\geq c_{p/q}{1\over 1-r}\log(1/(1-r))$ for $\theta = 2\pi p/q$

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is Stein Complex analysis Chapter 2 Problem 2.

> Let
> $$F(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty d(n)z^n\quad\text{for}\ |z|<1$$
> where $d(n)$ denotes the number of divisors of $n$. Then the radius of convergence is $1$ and
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(n)z^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {z^n\over 1-z^n}.$$
> If $z = r$ with $0<r<1$ then
> $$|F(r)|\geq c{1\over 1-r}\log(1/(1-r))$$
> as $r\to 1$.
> If $\theta = 2\pi p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are positive integers and $z = re^{i\theta}$, then
> $$|F(re^{i\theta})|\geq c_{p/q}{1\over 1-r}\log(1/(1-r))$$
> as $r\to 1$.

The first case can be done as follows:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty{r^n\over 1-r^n} & \geq \int_1^\infty{r^x\over 1-r^x}\ dx\\
& = {-1\over\log r}\log(1-r^x)\bigg|_1^\infty\\
& = -{1\over\log r}(0-\log(1-r))\\
& = {\log(1-r)\over\log r}\\
& \geq {1\over 1-r}\log\left({1\over 1-r}\right).\\
\end{align*}
Here, I used the fact that ${r^x\over 1-r^x}$ is monotone decreasing and $|\log r|\leq 1-r$ for $r<1$. The problem is $|F(re^{i\theta})|$ case. I think I can't use the same argument. There is a post asking the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2355465/668308) but it doesn't answer this question. I can't see why $\theta$ is restricted to the $2\pi p/q$ case only. Could you help?

Comment: For $z=re^{2\pi i p/q}$ the infinite series is periodic in $\theta$ so essentially you use the case $z=r$ (slightly modified but same ideas - for $n$ multiples of $q$ you get precisely that with $z\to z^q$...) $q$ times; the result cannot hold for arbitrary angles from general theory (analytic disc functions with infinite limits ae on unit circle do not exist)

Comment: @Conrad But still, exponential term is contained in the summand so I think I can't use integral estimate because eventually, I need to find a bound from below.

Comment: put an answer detailing the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=re^{2\pi i p/q}$ and note that for every $0 \le a \le q-1$ we have $z^{kq+a}=r^{kq+a}e^{2\pi i ap/q}, k=0,1,..$

Now we split the sum in $q$ susbsums as above and first we look at $a=0$ when we get $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty {r^{qk}\over 1-r^{qk}}$ and using the first case this is at least $$c(1/(1-r^q))\log(1/(1-r^q))=c_q(1/ (1-r))\log(1/(1-r))+O(1/(1-r))$$ by expanding the logarithm as $$\log(1/(1-r^q))=\log (1/(1-r))-\log (1+r+..r^{q-1})=\log (1/(1-r))+O(1)$$

Now if $1\le a \le q-1$ we notice (by taking real parts) that $$|1-r^{kq+a}e^{2\pi i ap/q}| \ge 1-\cos 2\pi ap/q =2\sin^2 \pi ap/q=\delta_{a,p,q}>0$$ so all the other $q-1$ subsums are less or equal $$ \sum_{a=1}^{q-1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty r^{qk+a}/\delta_{a,p,q}=\sum_{a=1}^{q-1}r^{a+q}/(1-r^q)=O(1/(1-r)) $$ so putting all together we get that $$|F(re^{2\pi ip/q})| \ge c_q{1\over 1-r}\log(1/(1-r))+O_{p,q}(1/(1-r))$$  so $$|F(re^{2\pi ip/q})| \ge c_{p,q}{1\over 1-r}\log(1/(1-r))$$
and we are done!

As noted no analytic function in the unit disc can have infinite radial limits ae so the result must fail for most $\theta$ that are not $2\pi p/q$

Comment: On the other $q-1$ subsums part, we need to find the lower bound of it. I think you found the upper bound of subsums.

Comment: what we find is that the subsums for $a \ne 0$ are bounded in absolute value by $c/(1-r)$; this makes them much smaller than the main sum for $a=0$ which has the extra logarithmic term which goes to infinity as $r \to 1$ and we use the fact that $|S_0+S_1+..S_{q-1}| \ge |S_0| -(|S_1|+...|S_{q-1}|$ so we need upper bounds for $S_a, 0<a \le q-1$ and lower bound for $S_0$